# ACF Query meta_values don't work with 'offset'

Tags: query-posts, advanced-custom-fields

I am currently building a featured posts section and I'm using ACF to set which posts will be featured. As they're appear in another section, I want them to start in this query on the third post. However, if I use the query below, it doesn't return anything:

```
<?php query_posts(
  array(
    'post_type'      => 'custom',
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'offset'         => '2'
    'meta_query'     => array(
      array(
        'key'     => 'featured',
        'compare' => '==',
        'value'   => '1'
      )
    )
  )
); ?>
```

It works with the `offset` or the `meta_query`, but not with both of them. Does anyone know how to address this issue?